# Word order of sentences with "included"

Tags: word-order, participles

For the participle "included", there are two options that both sound similar to me. However, one option might be preferred above the other. It might also be that there is an underlying grammatical rule that I don't know. It's about word order. Which of the following phrases should be used?

- Take a look at the **included** instructions.
- Take a look at the instructions **included**.

Is there a general rule that can be used here?

Comment: No rule, but I suspect that your first example where the verb phrase “included” modifies the noun “instructions” is more common than your second one where “instructions included” is a noun phrase where “instructions” is post-modified by the gerund-participial clause “included”.

Comment: Google seems to have it the other way around. The phrase "included instructions" has fewer than 1 million hits. The phrase "instructions included" has more than 8 million hits.

Comment: I've found out that the second might be at times obligatory, namely for postpositive adjectives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective. The article touches on something interesting. The first sentence might express an individual-level meaning, while the second might express a stage-level meaning (according to Greg Carlson). That means that the second admits that the instructions are now included, but are likely to be taken out. It's not an inherent property of the object "instructions" that they are included.